# Import Bootstrap min.css file in only one React Page

Tags: java, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a React Project with more than 2 Webpages.
And I also only want to include my bootstrap css file to my Page2.js but if i import it like:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

It has effect on all my pages but it should only change my Page2.js.
How can i import this css file for only one page?

Thanks :D

Comment: What do  you mean with "it has effect on all my pages"? Bootstrap classes don't kick in unless you assign them to your elements.

Comment: Lets say on Page1.js i imported a custom css with a button design in it. And the problem is that its named like a bootstrap class.Now in Page2.js I import the bootstrap.css and now my custom css on Page1.js gets overwritten by the bootstrap design.But i don’t want it.The bootstrap design should only take effect on Page2.ja because there I imported it.

Comment: That seems like it'd have an obvious fix: half the web uses bootstrap, don't give things the same names as bootstrap classes? As for "pages" there _are no pages_ in a React app. It's a single JS-managed application, and any styles import become a static asset that is bundled in and loaded along with everything else. If that's not what you want, you may need to have that one page explicitly create a `<link>` element for that css file instead, so that it only ends up in the DOM when react shows that one page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the css link in here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ in my index.html and it works